# Spring boot app not connecting with postgres DA via docker compose

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run a simple spring boot app with PostgreSQL via docker-compose.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  persons-java-api:
    container_name: persons-java-api
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    depends_on:
      - persons-db-service
  persons-db-service:
    container_name: persons-db-service
    image: postgres:14.4
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER:postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD:123456
      - POSTGRES_DB:persons-db
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

Spring application `Dockerfile`

```
FROM openjdk:11

WORKDIR /service
COPY target/person-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /service/app.jar
CMD ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

And here is the `application.properties` file of the spring app

```
server.port=8081
spring.application.name=person

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://persons-db-service:5432/persons-db
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=123456

#spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format-sql=true
```

when I run `docker-compose up` it fails with the following error

```
Attaching to persons-db-service, persons-java-api
persons-db-service  | Error: Database is uninitialized and superuser password is not specified.
persons-db-service  |        You must specify POSTGRES_PASSWORD to a non-empty value for the
persons-db-service  |        superuser. For example, "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" on "docker run".
persons-db-service  |
persons-db-service  |        You may also use "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust" to allow all
persons-db-service  |        connections without a password. This is *not* recommended.
persons-db-service  |
persons-db-service  |        See PostgreSQL documentation about "trust":
persons-db-service  |        https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-trust.html
persons-db-service exited with code 1Attaching to persons-db-service, persons-java-api
persons-db-service  | Error: Database is uninitialized and superuser password is not specified.
persons-db-service  |        You must specify POSTGRES_PASSWORD to a non-empty value for the
persons-db-service  |        superuser. For example, "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" on "docker run".
persons-db-service  |
persons-db-service  |        You may also use "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust" to allow all
persons-db-service  |        connections without a password. This is *not* recommended.
persons-db-service  |
persons-db-service  |        See PostgreSQL documentation about "trust":
persons-db-service  |        https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-trust.html
persons-db-service exited with code 1



org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
persons-java-api    |   at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:331) ~[postgresql-42.3.5.jar!/:42.3.5]
persons-java-api    |   at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.3.5.jar!/:42.3.5]
persons-java-api    |   at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223) ~[postgresql-42.3.5.jar!/:42.3.5]
persons-java-api    |   at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:402) ~[postgresql-42.3.5.jar!/:42.3.5]
persons-java-api    |   at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:261) ~[postgresql-42.3.5.jar!/:42.3.5]
persons-java-api    |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
persons-java-api    |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
persons-java-api    |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
persons-java-api    |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
persons-java-api    |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
persons-java-api    |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
persons-java-api    |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
persons-java-api    |   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
persons-java-api    |   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]

persons-java-api    | Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: persons-db
persons-java-api    |   at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:229) ~[na:na]
persons-java-api    |   at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:na]
persons-java-api    |   at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609) ~[na:na]
persons-java-api    |   at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:241) ~[postgresql-42.3.5.jar!/:42.3.5]
persons-java-api    |   at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:98) ~[postgresql-42.3.5.jar!/:42.3.5]
persons-java-api    |   at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:109) ~[postgresql-42.3.5.jar!/:42.3.5]
persons-java-api    |   at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:235) ~[postgresql-42.3.5.jar!/:42.3.5]
persons-java-api    |   ... 57 common frames omitted
```

Can someone kindly what I am doing incorrectly here?

Comment: You need spaces after the colons in the environment variables; `POSTGRES_PASSWORD: '123456'`.  Or change the colons to equal signs, `POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123456`.

Comment: Both of these should be on same docker virtual network
https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Answer (score 0):

Seems that i have to also add spring.datsource.url to compose file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://persons-db-service:5432/persons-db
```

whole working compose file is

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  persons-java-api:
    container_name: persons-java-api
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      - spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://persons-db-service:5432/persons-db
    depends_on:
      - persons-db-service

  persons-db-service:
    container_name: persons-db-service
    image: postgres:${POSTGRES_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_USER_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

The environment variable are coming from `.env` file